# Textbook on information theory for mathematicians

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, information-theory

All of the information theory textbooks I've seen seem to be targeted towards computer scientists. Is there a good textbook that is targeted towards mathematicians?

Comment: [entropy and information theory](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwiGht_Au4LnAhUFGDQIHefxA_oQFjAAegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fee.stanford.edu%2F~gray%2Fit.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3ggBeV0XNJMIgreYfkZE4V)

Answer (score 4):

My favourite is Imre Csiszar and Janos Korner's *Information Theory: Coding Theorems for Discrete Memoryless Systems*, see [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/information-theory/A441D8792B877693D6F91E8D61B53F42) which first appeared in the early 80's.

The updated 2nd Edition has more network information theory, but the first edition is very comprehensive as well, and is more detailed in its earlier foundational chapters. It is largely based on the combinatorial approach to information theory.

As in the comments, the Robert Gray book *Entropy and Information Theory* available online [here](https://ee.stanford.edu/~gray/it.pdf) is another great book which is targeted towards mathematicians. It provides a complement to the first book in that it treats more complicated and not necessarily independent stochastic processes.